# select2 function no working even using from a CDN

Tags: php, laravel

I have add this 2 line for select2 function which is

> ```
> <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
> <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
> ```

and in the view file I add this as below:

```
         <select id="cat_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="">please select a category</option>
            <option value="saab">A</option>
            <option value="saab">B</option>
            <option value="saab">C</option>
         </select>
```

Alright, to make it works I add this script as below

```html
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cat_id').select2();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: call jquery file and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, it will help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="cat_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="">please select a category</option>
            <option value="saab">A</option>
            <option value="saab">B</option>
            <option value="saab">C</option>
         </select>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cat_id').select2();
});
</script>
```

it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

include jquery link too and try

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cat_id').select2();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>


  <select id="cat_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="">please select a category</option>
            <option value="saab">A</option>
            <option value="saab">B</option>
            <option value="saab">C</option>
         </select>


          <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cat_id').select2();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add **jQuery** library before **Select 2** library and it will work.

**N.B.** If you use **slim version** of **jQuery** it may not **work**.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.noConflict();` before you code. I think you library is included twice or may be conflict.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict(); // Remove jquery conflict
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cat_id').select2();
    });
</script>
```